# Divide all rows by a reference row, by group

Tags: r

Here is a sample table I'm working with:

```
n = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3))
m = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z")
s = 1:9 
b = 5:13
c = 20:28
d = c(rep("abc", 9))
df = data.frame(d, n, m, s, b, c) 
df
```

Below is what the table looks like:

```
d   n   m   s   b   c
abc A   X   1   5   20
abc A   Y   2   6   21
abc A   Z   3   7   22
abc B   X   4   8   23
abc B   Y   5   9   24
abc B   Z   6   10  25
abc C   X   7   11  26
abc C   Y   8   12  27
abc C   Z   9   13  28
```

I'll refer to each row as a concatenation of its column n and m values (e.g. AX row, CZ row, etc.) I would like to divide each of the A rows by the AY row, each of the B rows by the BY row, and each of the C rows by the CY row (may not always be Y, sometimes X or Z). I essentially want to rebase the data (columns s, b, and c) by group (where column n is the group), using X, Y, or Z (column m) as the base.

I need columns d, n, and m to remain untouched. If possible, I'd like to do this by referencing X, Y, or Z in the code directly to denote which row will be the base, rather than by [1], [2], or [3] (as they may not always be in the same order, and it's more intuitive to the user). I'm new to R and using dplyr but I haven't been able to figure out a good way of doing this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

divselect <- "Y"

set(df, j = "s", value = as.numeric(df[["s"]]))
set(df, j = "b", value = as.numeric(df[["b"]]))
set(df, j = "c", value = as.numeric(df[["c"]]))
```

The `set` commands are to avoid an error. The columns currently are `integer`, but you're going to be making them `double`. If in your real world example they're already `double` this won't be necessary.

The value of `divselect` changes which column rows you're using as your base. You can change this to `X` or `Z` as needed.

```
df[, `:=`(s = s/s[m == divselect],
          b = b/b[m == divselect],
          c = c/c[m == divselect]),
   by = n]
```

Result:

```
#      d n m     s         b         c
# 1: abc A X 0.500 0.8333333 0.9523810
# 2: abc A Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 3: abc A Z 1.500 1.1666667 1.0476190
# 4: abc B X 0.800 0.8888889 0.9583333
# 5: abc B Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 6: abc B Z 1.200 1.1111111 1.0416667
# 7: abc C X 0.875 0.9166667 0.9629630
# 8: abc C Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 9: abc C Z 1.125 1.0833333 1.0370370
```

### Followup

> I have one question: is there a way to generalize the columns that get
>   rebased? I'd like this code to be able to handle additional numeric
>   columns (more than 3 without calling each out specifically). i.e. Can
>   I define the division to happen to all columns except d, n, and m?

Yes, you can do this by using `lapply` either inside or outside the `data.table`.

```
setDT(df)

divselect <- "Y"

funcnumeric <- function(x) {
  set(df, j = x, value = as.numeric(df[[x]]))
  NULL
}

modcols <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% c("d", "n", "m"))]

a <- lapply(modcols, funcnumeric)
```

This replaces the three `set` commands in the first answer. Instead of specifying each, we use `lapply` to perform the function on each column that is not `d`, `n`, or `m`. Note that I return NULL to avoid messy function return text; since this is `data.table` it is all done in place.

```
funcdiv <- function(x, pos) {
  x/x[pos]
}

df[ , (modcols) := lapply(.SD, 
                          funcdiv, 
                          pos = which(m == divselect)), 
    by = n, 
    .SDcols = modcols]
```

This is done slightly different than before. Here we create a simple function that will divide a vector by that vector's value a the position specified by the `pos` parameter. We apply that to each column in `.SD`, and also pass the `pos` value as the position where the `m` column is equal to the value of `divselect`, in this case it is equal to `Y`. Since we are specifying `by = n` both the vector and `pos` arguments to `funcdiv` will be determined for each value in `n`. The parameter `.SDcols` specifies that we want to `lapply` this function, which is the same set of columns that we assigned to the variable `modcols`. We assign all of this back to `modcols` in place.

Result:

```
#      d n m     s         b         c
# 1: abc A X 0.500 0.8333333 0.9523810
# 2: abc A Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 3: abc A Z 1.500 1.1666667 1.0476190
# 4: abc B X 0.800 0.8888889 0.9583333
# 5: abc B Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 6: abc B Z 1.200 1.1111111 1.0416667
# 7: abc C X 0.875 0.9166667 0.9629630
# 8: abc C Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 9: abc C Z 1.125 1.0833333 1.0370370
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. I have one question: is there a way to generalize the columns that get rebased? I'd like this code to be able to handle additional numeric columns (more than 3 without calling each out specifically). i.e. Can I define the division to happen to all columns except d, n, and m?

Comment: Yes, added some code to the answer that should now generalize to perform the calculation on any column other than d, n, or m.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It'll take me a bit to understand exactly what this code is doing, but I really appreciate your follow-up response.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
df2 <- filter(df, m=="Y") %>% setNames(.,c("e","n","f","g","h","i"))
df1 <- full_join(df,df2,by="n") %>%
          mutate(s=s/g, b=b/h, c=c/i) %>%
          select(-c(e,f,g,h,i))
```

Output

```
    d n m     s         b         c
1 abc A X 0.500 0.8333333 0.9523810
2 abc A Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
3 abc A Z 1.500 1.1666667 1.0476190
4 abc B X 0.800 0.8888889 0.9583333
5 abc B Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
6 abc B Z 1.200 1.1111111 1.0416667
7 abc C X 0.875 0.9166667 0.9629630
8 abc C Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
9 abc C Z 1.125 1.0833333 1.0370370
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your data,  we can build a table of the rows to divide by and then pick the table row using `match`

```
table = df[which(df$m == "Y"), c(2,4:6)]
New_df = df
New_df[, 4:6] = New_df[,4:6]/table[match(df$n, table$n), 2:4]
New_df
    d n m     s         b         c
1 abc A X 0.500 0.8333333 0.9523810
2 abc A Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
3 abc A Z 1.500 1.1666667 1.0476190
4 abc B X 0.800 0.8888889 0.9583333
5 abc B Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
6 abc B Z 1.200 1.1111111 1.0416667
7 abc C X 0.875 0.9166667 0.9629630
8 abc C Y 1.000 1.0000000 1.0000000
9 abc C Z 1.125 1.0833333 1.0370370
```